# PHP-inserted text file inside <pre> tag causing large offset of first line

Tags: html, pre, php-include

Im inserting code snippets in my website using the `<pre>` tag.

Here is the HTML/PHP code:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
    <?php include('canny.py'); ?>
</pre>
```

And here is the content of `canny.py`:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('/path/to/file/line_02.jpg', 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
cv2.imwrite('mycanny.jpg', edges)
```

However, for some reason the first line renders like 3 or 4 tabs away from the left margin of the div element. And this only happens in the first line i.e, if i leave the first line of the .py file empty, the second line still renders fine.

[image]

Why is this happening, what is the way to make it work properly?

Comment: Remove the spaces between `<pre>` and `<?php`?

Comment: Yes, works. Feeling really stupid : (

Comment: Please ask Ryan to add an answer to get rid of the status of this question of being unanswered.

Comment: Maybe the question is worth deleting? Not sure about the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the four spaces between your opening `<pre>` tag and the PHP tag `<?php`.

These are interpreted literally and the content that your PHP script reads is inserted after these four spaces, therefore your first line is offset by the same.

```
<pre class="prettyprint"><?php include('canny.py'); ?></pre>
```

should work.